# R - kableExtra - How to densify as much as possible the html output of a table to then convert it into word

Tags: html, r, ms-word, kable, kableextra

I have a table generated in R of the following form. What I want to do is copy this table from the html output (after `knit to html`) into word for a scientific paper that I have to write. It's rather complicated, but it is the only way I found to have that table in an editable format which is required from the journal to which I will submit the article with the table (first question: I would be glad to know if there is another way to do it). As the table is quite big, the main question is how to have the text as packed as possible und have the space between line as small as possible so that when copying from the html document into word, I don't spend 20 minutes to adjust the layout in word.
Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

mydf <- data.frame(
  # group = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
  row = c(1:16),
  group = c("group 1.1<br>group1.2", "group 2", "group 3", "group 4", "group 5", "group 6", "group 7", "group 8", "group 1.1<br>group1.2", "group 2", "group 3", "group 4", "group 5", "group 6", "group 7", "group 8")
)

mydf %>%
  kable("html", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand, so I hope I'm in the right direction. 
What if you'll edit the `kable_styling` arguments?

```
mydf %>%
  kable("html", escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, 
                font_size = 12, 
                position = "left")
```

In addition, if you're looking for APA tables, depend on your analysis, you can try the [`apaTables`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apaTables/index.html) and [`apa`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apa/index.html) packages.

Comment: Thank you very much @DJV for your answer that I upvoted. However the output is not as packed as the output that I get when I `knit to pdf` the document. But it's a beginning. I will also check the `apa` package. Does it do html output as well?

Comment: Glad I could somewhat help you. Regarding the APA packages, they export to word documents.

Comment: I just checked `apaTables` out: it looks really great! The thing is that it looks like the package performs both statistical analysis (ANOVA, correlation, linear regression and so on) AND ouput in word. As I already did the statistical analysis and stored them in a dataframe, do you have an idea if it's possible to use apaTables` and output it in word without performing any stat?

Comment: Unfortunately not more than `kable` as to offer. From some google search, you can try to look here (https://dmyee.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/table_workshop.pdf). However, most of the packages will force you "recalculate"

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your help @DJV